# Web Analytics site scope and subsites

Tags: web-analytics

I work on a corporate intranet taht use SharePoint 2010 publishing.

Let's say I have this web structure:

```
(root)
  Pages in /pages
  1. subweb 1
      --> Pages in /subweb1/pages
     1.1 subweb 1.1
          --> Pages in /subweb1/subweb11/pages
     1.2 subweb 1.2
          --> Pages in /subweb1/subweb12/pages
  2. subweb 2
      --> Pages in /subweb1/pages
     2.1 subweb 2.1
          --> Pages in /subweb2/subweb21/pages
     2.2 subweb 2.2
          --> Pages in /subweb2/subweb22/pages
```

(actually the structure has more depth level, but this is enough to illustrate my issue).

There are several content in all page libraries and everything is checked in.

The WebAnalytics service is running and seems to work as expected (except the issue describe below).

I'm puzzled, because the "Top pages" report, **site-scoped**, will show only contents of the **root web site** when using the report at the root.

But in subweb, reports will show the results from the subweb and all of its children.

To sum, what I observe:

- The site collection top page reports will show pages from the whole site collection, whichever site I'm connected to.
- the top page report of the **root** will display content only from the root website
- the top page report of the **subweb1** will display content of **subweb1** but also from all its descendants (**subweb1.1**, ...).

The second line is what is wrong. How can I display web analytics data, from the root, but that also include children, like it's the case for subwebs?

PS: I'm actually accessing this data from code, that's why I always use the site scoped report.